# How to keep React Native animated transform state?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-animatable

Why I animate the Animated.View with `transform` style, it works.
But when I update some data (with `useState`), the `transformed` status will go back to the origin.
However, other style properties, like `padding`, will keep the updated value.
Why and how to solve it?

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Just using `new Animated.Value(0)` then `Animated.timing...`
And I found it works as expected in Android(simulator)--it will keep the transformed status, but not in iOS!

Comment: use **useRef** hook.

Comment: @LeriGogsadze Oh thanks it works!   
I am curious why does it work without useRef in Android...